# css :hover not working anyway

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

Some time ago :hover in css went fine,but I did some changes(I forgot) and now it is not working

```css
.nav-bar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar:hover {
  color: #B0BEC5;
}

.nav-bar span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You change the colour on `:hover`, but there is no text to change the colour of. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: **Hint**: you can make your HTML/CSS into a runnable Stack Snippet with the click of an editor button. This way, we can reproduce your issue easily. @Quentin did it for you this time, but something to keep in mind for your next question. :)

Comment: You need to chnage background color of the nav bar right?

Comment: Thank u all,I couldn't see.I fixed )

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the bar's background color on hover

replace this:

```
.nav-bar:hover {
   color: #B0BEC5;
}
```

with this:

```
.nav-bar:hover span{
    background: #B0BEC5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 slight errors in your code, change:

```
.nav-bar:hover {
  color: #B0BEC5;
}
```

To

```
.nav-bar:hover > span {
    background-color: #B0BEC5;
}
```

Then it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the hover within the nav-bar but on the span:

```css
.nav-bar {
}

.nav-bar span {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar span:hover{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <span>NavA</span>
  <span>NavB</span>
  <span>NavC</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is perfect. Just change hover effect.

```
.nav-bar:hover {
   background: #B0BEC5;
}
```

You add css `color : #B0BEC5` which change color of text, where as there is no text.

Comment: I changed it to 
`.nav-bar:hover span{
   background: #B0BEC5;
}`
and worked perfect